# How to remove items from the recent list in Steam's tray icon?

Tags: steam

I watched some videos from my Steam library *over a year ago*, they show up under Library → Recent and, this is the nagging part, in the indicator/systray area in Gnome Shell and XFCE (on a different computer!). Is there any way I can clean this up a bit or limit the amount of items displayed? A list of games would be okay but video episodes of how a game was made isn't very useful, I think.

[image]

I already unchecked the Library option in Settings → Interface → **Set Taskbar Preferences** and restarted Steam, but this had no effect.

[image]

I could check the "Hide this game in my library" option through "Set Categories…" but that doesn't seem to be a good solution and I don't know how I would find the content again if I hide it, I checked the corresponding store page and I'm still in doubt about that. I tried creating a category for all the videos, but that didn't group them together as I had hoped from what it said it the menu. Of course I also tried deleting the items from the recent queue using the <kbd>del</kbd> key.

Can anybody help please? Is it probably just some .desktop or XML files that can be edited?